# How to make a bot find a channel owner / compare to the author's ID

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a bot where if you do `d!move`, the bot will move the channel where the message was sent in under a category via ID. I also want to make it so that whoever does the command has permissions such as `MANAGE_CHANNELS`, which I've already added. The problem is that when I want to confirm whoever created that channel is the person that activated the command, the bot says yes. I did this on an alt account, where I made the channel and my alt was the one initializing it, and the bot said "success!" I also wanted to make it so if someone else made the channel, and when I did it, it would work because I made the bot know my ID.

I've researched Google and found nothing.

I've tried using a function with fetchAuditlog but get anywhere.

```
    if(!message.channel.client.user.id == message.author || !message.author.id == `329023088517971969`) return message.channel.send("You don't own this channel!")
    else message.channel.send("success!"); 
    message.channel.setParent(`576976244575305759`);
```

I expect the bot to be able to check if the author created the channel, and lead to `You don't own this channel` if they don't own it. But if they do then the bot moves the channel.

The actual result is the bot moving the channel anyway regardless if they own the channel or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *@André* has pointed out, `channel.client` represents the client itself, not the user who created the channel. Also, the last line in your code is not part of the `else` statement, so that's why it's run regardless of the conditions you defined.

To reach a solution, you can make use of the guild's audit logs. You can search for entries where the user is the message author and a channel was created. Then, all you have left is to check if one of those entries is for the current channel, and run the rest of your code if so.

Sample:

```js
message.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
  user: message.author,
  type: 'CHANNEL_CREATE'
}).then(logs => {
  if (!logs.entries.find(e => e.target && e.target.id === message.channel.id)) return message.channel.send('You don\'t own this channel.');
  else {
    // rest of code
  }
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I have an error at the `e.target.id` portion of the code, it says
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`
I attempted to define target and "e", and this didn't work. I did this on an alt account  and that's when I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

When you go `<anything>.client.user` it will return the bot client.
If you want to see who created the channel you would have to check the Audit Logs or save it internally.

> I've checked the documents. Here's what it says for .client about the
>   channel. It says the person that **initialized** the channel, or the
>   person that created it.

[On documentation I see this:](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=client)

> The client that **instantiated** the Channel

**instantiated** is different of **initialized**

Comment: I've changed up the code so that it's
`let chann = message.channel
 let creator = message.guild.fetchAuditLogs({type: 'CHANNEL_CREATE'})

    if(!creator.executor.id == message.author.id || !message.author.id == '329023088517971969') return message.channel.send("You don't own this channel!")`

Yet I haven't found a function for the bot to find who made the channel the message was sent in.

Comment: You looking for all the audit logs for all the channels that were created.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I make it so the bot searches for the channel created the message was sent in? Then it will take the user's ID, and if the creator's ID is equal to the author's ID, then it will do a function.